# How to use axios modular API in Vue CDN

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router

I have an HTML and referenced vue and vue-router

Now if I want to use axios, I can get the return data by calling the path directly

But I hope I can set up files to centrally manage apiUrl and apiName and import them

**index.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/http-vue-loader"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/api/server.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p>
            <router-link to="/contact">Go to contact</router-link>
        </p>
        <p>
            <router-link to="/about">Go to about</router-link>
        </p>
        <p>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </p>
    </div>

    <head>
        <script>
            const contact = httpVueLoader('./view/contact.vue')
            const about = httpVueLoader('./view/about.vue')

            const routes = [
                { path: '/contact', component: contact },
                { path: '/about', component: about }
            ]

            const router = new VueRouter({
                routes
            })

            var app = new Vue({
                router,
            }).$mount('#app')

        </script>


    </head>
</body>
</html>
```

**contact.vue**

```js
<template>
  <p>{{ hello }}</p>
</template>


<script>

module.exports = {
  data: function () {
    return {
      hello: "contact",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    
    axios
      .get('apiUrl/apiName')
      .then(response => (console.log(response.data))
      .catch(function (error) { 
        console.log(error);
      });

    
    
  },
};
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Currently, data can be obtained through directly defined paths. I am not using Node.js. Is it possible to modularize apiUrl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set [`axios`'s default `baseURL`](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults) so that all requests share the same URL prefixed to their paths:

```js
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'
```

I would do this in `index.html` before loading any components that would make `axios` requests.